# map-reduce cpu usage

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am running hadoop map reduce job of 4 node cluster. When I run this job, all nodes are hung up and other processes does not respond. In other words these 4 nodes becomes slow.

I did not set any parameters while running this job. Everything is default.

```
hadoop com.api.hadoop.ApiDriver -D job.name=newjob -D mapred.reduce.tasks=1 
    -D mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps=0 /apilog128 /apiout
```

What parameters affect the amount of CPU usage in data nodes?